# How to extend formulas and validation to newly added row (using "Add more rows" at the bottom, not using insert)?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have formulas and validation in columns D, E, L, M and N. I want these formulas and validation to be automatic whenever I add rows using the option "Add more rows at the bottom", not using insert or copy & paste.

[image: Sheets example]

Is it possible to do it and if so can you please create a code for me?

Comment: This will copy formulas and values from the row above: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/47171/how-to-automatically-insert-a-new-row-and-retain-functions-formulas-from-last-ro

Comment: I did try this but it didn't work. I've done my homework prior to asking the question. I can't seem to find an answer anywhere. And that's when I posted this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: 
 fixed version of this: [How to automatically insert a new row and retain functions/formulas from last row?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/47171/how-to-automatically-insert-a-new-row-and-retain-functions-formulas-from-last-ro)

Also copies data validation rules.

### Code

```
// global 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

function onOpen() {
  var menu = [{name:"Add New Last Row", functionName:"addRow"}];
  ss.addMenu("Extra", menu);
}

function addRow() {
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet(), lRow = sh.getLastRow(); 
  var lCol = sh.getLastColumn(), range = sh.getRange(lRow,1,1,lCol);
  sh.insertRowsAfter(lRow, 1);
  range.copyTo(sh.getRange(lRow+1, 1, 1, lCol), {contentsOnly:false});
}
```

Comment: How and what's the code? Thanks

Comment: Show us the money Eddy.

Comment: @user54830 can you please "have a go" at creating a solution.

Comment: I don't know how to. I wouldn't ask for help if I do.

Comment: (Edit) added a fixed copy of this answer: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/47171/how-to-automatically-insert-a-new-row-and-retain-functions-formulas-from-last-ro

Comment: @user54830 can you return the favour. My aim is to help spreadsheet users, spreadhsheet users who know how to use formulas, but don't know how to program. Am looking for feed back on this: www.cellmaster.com.au/Builder.html

Comment: Wow, Eddy, nice piece of code.