# Add new row while keeping functions in new Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

In the new Google Spreadsheets, I'm trying to make a simple spreadsheet which will assign points to my salesmen regarding some actions they complete.

[image]

I would like to be able to add a new row below the 2nd row that replicates the formula I have in column "U":

```
=COUNTIF(H3:Q3,"email")+(COUNTIF(H3:Q3,"response")*2)+(COUNTIF(H3:Q3,"call")*5)+(COUNTIF(H3:Q3,"deal")*10)
```

Ideally, in Excel I would use a macro, but I'm lost here...

Comment: Perhaps this answer is of use: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/47204/29140

Answer (score 1):

Either I'm totally misunderstanding what the problem is, or this is very easy with no macros required (in either tool).

Making a new row is easy, just select row 2, and then choose *Insert* → **Row below** from the menus.

Then, to replicate the formula you have in column U (I'm assuming just in the new cell is that row):

- click on one the formula in one of the other rows;
- press <kbd>F2</kbd>, to go into editing mode select the whole formula;
- copy it—<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>;
- click into the cell where you need to place it;
- paste it—<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, I think I explained myself wrong (English is not my first language, sorry!). 

I could add the row and copy the formula, but I would like to do that in one movement.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps Script (GAS) Google spreadsheets could be used in a similar way that Macros are used in Excel.

In the first reference below you could find how to start with GAS. The second reference was shared in a comment to the question that includes a script and example that could be used to start with.

**References**
[Extend Google Docs, Sheets, and Forms with Apps Script - Docs editors help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=en)
[How to automatically insert a new row and retain functions/formulas from last row?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/47171/how-to-automatically-insert-a-new-row-and-retain-functions-formulas-from-last-ro/)