# How to copy range from last row to a new row created via script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I saw the below code at [How to automatically insert a new row and retain functions/formulas from last row?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/47171/how-to-automatically-insert-a-new-row-and-retain-functions-formulas-from-last-ro/47204#47204?newreg=9d6d013b507c4dd98104218a091e2834), and have a question on how to modify it so that instead of copying all content from the last row to the new one, I'd like to copy only a range of cells from the last row.

```
// global 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

function onOpen() {
  var menu = [{name:"Add New Last Row", functionName:"addRow"}];
  ss.addMenu("Extra", menu);
}

function addRow() {
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet(), lRow = sh.getLastRow(); 
  var lCol = sh.getLastColumn(), range = sh.getRange(lRow,1,1,lCol);
  sh.insertRowsAfter(lRow, 1);
  range.copyTo(sh.getRange(lRow+1, 1, 1, lCol), {contentsOnly:false});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could change  `range = sh.getRange(lRow,1,1,lCol)` to fit your needs.

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)

> #### getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)
>
> Returns the range with the top left cell at the given coordinates with
>   the given number of rows and columns.

(follow the above link to see a code example)

> ```
> Parameters
>
> Name          Type          Description
> row           Integer     the starting row of the range
> column        Integer     the starting column of the range
> numRows       Integer     the number of rows to return
> numColumns    Integer     the number of columns to return
> ```