# Automatically add rows based on condition of existing rows

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to have a formula on a Google Sheets spreadsheet that checks the content of the existing top Nth rows, and adds extra rows based on the content of these.

I read this question:
[How to automatically insert a new row and retain functions/formulas from last row?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/47171/how-to-automatically-insert-a-new-row-and-retain-functions-formulas-from-last-ro)

But it seems like the trigger here is when the spreadsheet is opened (onOpen() function?), rather than a condition on existing rows.

[Here is an example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aoLBO2mAq8_BWB1z7s-wNxumdW9lWf1CgtJH8KXnD5Y)

[image: an example]

The spreadsheet has a header, and similarly to the question posted above, I would like to add a new row by checking on the content of the existing ones.

For example, given the fact that the users are going to be filling in the columns from bottom upwards, I would like a trigger that adds a new row 2 with `Entry452 / NA / NA / NA`, keeping the same formulas, etc. as `Entry451`, and it does so when we are running out of empty rows. E.g., when there are less than five rows left with NAs in column machine_type.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps?

```
function conditionalNewRow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var headerRow = 1;
  var firstRow = headerRow + 1;
  var range = sh.getRange("A2:D2"); // Get range of row 2.
  var futureRange = sh.getRange("A3:D3"); // Get range of row 3.
  var numCols = range.getNumColumns(); // Get the number of columns for row 2.
  var contentVal = false;

  for (i = 1; i <= numCols; i++) {
    var currentValue = range.getCell(1,i).getValue();
    if (currentValue == "NA"){
      contentVal = true;
      break;
    }
  }  
  if (contentVal == true) {
    sh.insertRowBefore(firstRow); // Insert an empty row into row 2.       
    futureRange.copyTo(sh.getRange(firstRow, 1, firstRow, numCols), {contentsOnly:false}); // Copy row 3 to row 2.
  }
}
```