# How to make arrayformula automatically applied to newly inserted rows?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

The following arrayformula needs to be applied to the entire column B, so that it populates Twitter account IDs in the cells of Column B according to hyperlinks in Column A. It firstly checks whether the cell in Column A is empty. If empty, leave the cell in Column B empty; if not empty, populates the cell in Column B with a Twitter account ID according to the hyperlink in the cell of Column A.

```
=arrayformula(IF(A1="",,IF(REGEXMATCH(A1, "twitter\.com/[^/]+"), REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "twitter\.com/([^/]+)"),)))
```

But the problem is that, every time I and my coworkers "Insert 1 row above", the arrayformula is not automatically applied to the newly inserted row.

I found a [10-year old solution](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/47204/262158), but not sure whether it's still an optimal one. I did not see any option for adding script in the Tools menu as the solution described. But I saw a similar option called "Apps Script" in the Extension menu. And I tried creating a script with that option but didn't know what to do next. After I press the Debug button, it says something like authentication is required. The owner of the spreadsheet is one of my coworker, so I myself cannot do the authentication directly.

Incidentally, the purpose of populating Twitter account IDs in Column B is for finding duplicates in Column B. And that's because one Twitter account can only have one hyperlink in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reserve row `1` for headers by choosing **View > Freeze > 1 row** and change your workflow so that you always insert new rows *below* row `1`.

Then clear column `B` and put this formula in cell `B1`:

```
=arrayformula(if( 
  row(A1:A) = 1, 
  "Accounts", 
  iferror(regexextract(A2:A, "twitter\.com/([^/]+)")) 
))
```